# How do i iterate through coordinates from an api call to create multiple points on openlayers 3.

Tags: reactjs, openlayers-3

I am trying to use openlayers 3 with react.js to render multiple points to a map based on a collection of latitude and longitude pairs returned from an api call.  What would be the best format for an iteration to perform this task in react.js?